# Google Maps Business API Implementation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hoping someone can just help as to whether my code is working or not (before I post any code).

On behalf of my web client, we have registered for the Google Maps Business API and this has all come through fine.

I have been trying to implement to the Client ID and Crypto key into the pages so that it runs off this and doesn't hit the free usage policy. The map seems to be working with the signature in place and the API portal seems to be registering hits in the API for Business Usage Report (web services report) in the user Portal. These hits were my tests on the 29th November. On a note, if I change the client ID the map breaks so it is definitely hitting this.

Do I take it from these results that the API has been implemented successfully? I cannot see any other stats being reported in the portal.

If any one can provide any help then that would be great.

Kind regards.

Comment: **Google Maps Business API** comes with support from **Google**